# Dúvida na análise de complexidade de um algorítmo

Tags: algoritmo, recursão

Preciso saber como cálcular a complexidade deste algoritmo usando a equação de recorrência.

```
public int qdr(int x, int n) {
   if(n == 0)
     return 1;
   else
     return x * qdr(x, n-1);
}
```

> **É um algorítmo recursivo que lê dois números x e n e retorna o resultado de x^n**

Comment: Trabalho de casa lol

Comment: @JorgeB. é lista de exercicios da Faculdade, é que tenho prova hoje e preciso entender como calcular a complexidade de algorítmos recursivos usando a equação de recorrência kk

Comment: http://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lume.ufrgs.br%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F10183%2F2133%2F000269187.pdf%3Fsequence%3D1&ei=8M0NVNe4NI7baPD3gKAO&usg=AFQjCNFSPyxFnXICkysTLdYb55euDvnjzw&sig2=9too9nxJemYZtqqZfmC-NQ&bvm=bv.74649129,d.d2s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e bem simples :)

quando `n > 1`, a função faz uma operação  que tem tempo constante, a multiplicação, e faz uma chamada recursiva que tem tamanho `n - 1`.

logo, a recorrência fica:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 (ou O(1), da na mesma)
T(1) = 1
```

se você resolver você vai chegar em uma soma do tipo `1 + 1 + 1+ ... + 1`, com `n` uns. isso da `n`. logo, a função é linear, `O(n)`.

Comment: entendi, vou continuar estudando aqui :D valeu!